# poor audio quality with OpenAL on iOS/OSX

Tags: ios, openal

I find myself porting an old multimedia title to iOS/OSX and I'm somewhat disappointed with the quality of audio output I've achieved via OpenAL, in that it's got that "scratchy" quality one hears when PCM is resampled poorly.  However, I'm feeding it 8-bit PCM at 11025KHz and I do believe the native rate is 44100KHz so I can't imagine why anything other than a 1:4 integral expansion of the samples would be occurring.  The sound itself is very clean when played back on a Win32 system so I know there's no problems with the data itself.  Nor are there any buffering problems in that I'm keeping about 32K buffered ahead of the playback position.  But the sound quality just isn't that good.  Has anyone else encountered this and are there configuration options to work around it?  I've gone through the docs and nothing seems applicable to the problem ...

Comment: 8-bit at 11kHz is officially "Lo-Fi". it's good that you mentioned the signal sounds fine on another system. for *some* signals, 8/11kHz is all that's needed.

Comment: Well, the data is what it is.  It's a children's product and the audio is mostly dialogue and ambient noises so 11KHz seems quite adequate.  It certainly was 15 or so years ago and I can't imagine today's generation of 8 year olds caring any more than last generation's.  Anyway, the software was definitely not schlock way back when and a lot of time and effort went into preparing the audio, even though it was only "Lo-Fo" by today's standards ...

Comment: It's the equivalent of a modern mastered rock recording with a LPF (reference to volume wars). Have you tried converting it to 16/44.1? Does it sound Ok? Does 8/44.1 sound Ok? Does 16/11025 sound Ok? Is there any difference in the quality?

Comment: Per my other comments below, I'll try that.  It's just a little surprising/disappointing that OpenAL would fail at such a basic task as up-sampling 11KHz to 44KHz, when it's supposedly capable of doing so much more.  Wondering how different Apple's implementation is from the mainstream right now since I'm considering using OpenAL on Android just to save some time.  Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS doesn't handle 8-bit data very well. Try converting it to 16-bit.

```
afconvert -f caff -d LEI16@11025 sourcefile.wav destfile.caf
```

You could also compress it to mp3 or aac, but that's a little more complicated to load since it needs to be converted to 16-bit little endian format when loaded.

Here's a loader that handles any 16-bit audio format: https://github.com/kstenerud/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/blob/master/ObjectAL/ObjectAL/Support/OALAudioFile.m

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll try that.  Pretty darned easy to do.  I just imagined that whoever wrote OpenAL would've felt the same and gotten it right.  I mean, if that's all it takes to make it sound ok then someone screwed up at a very basic level ...

Comment: Lots of Apple stuff tends to be that way when you stray from the common case, unfortunately.